# PNG/Bitmap to Windows Clipboard

Tags: c++, windows, clipboard

Trying to put the contents of a PNG file onto the clipboard.   I am generating a QRCode using qrcode.exe.  Output from that is a PNG.

It loads like this:

```
CBitmap bmp;
CImage image;
image.Load( _T("full-file-path-to-png-file")  );
bmp.Attach( image.Detach() );
```

I've had no problem displaying it in a dialog using using CStatic::SetBitmap.

BUT! I am unable to get this thing onto the clipboard, using this:

```
void CMyDialog::SetClipboardBitmap( CBitmap& bmp )
{
    if ( OpenClipboard() )
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData( CF_BITMAP, bmp.GetSafeHandle() );
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

The CF_BITMAP does appear onto the clipboard, but seems to be a null (0 x 0) image...  Any clues out there for me?

Comment: Using your code in a non-mfc app, with a 1-bit BMP file pulled from the application's resources works just fine. Switching to a 24 bit BMP image, I can still see the image on the dialog, but it fails to copy. If I use GDI+ to load a 32bit png image, the result is a fail. Similarly, using the working BMP file, saved as a 1bit png also fails. Finally, using GDI+ to load the bmp file that works when embedded as a resource, there is also a zero-output result. Perhaps you need to employ the CF_DIB format instead.

Comment: I've sorta come to that same conclusion...  that my bitmap data is not compatible with CF_BITMAP.   I've been writing code for Windows for a very long time, and this is the first time I've ever dealt with the clipboard for something that's not text.

I guess the dummy in me, assumes that a CBitmap is always the same as CF_BITMAP.

Comment: As an experiment, I decided to use some code from LeadTools to see if I could make it work -- and it did on the first try.  Luckily, we have a license for that.   The leadtools image loader I have converts the PNG to a DDB before attaching it to a CBitmap.  This seems to imply that CF_DIB might have been the answer.

Comment: Good info, thanks for the update Lompican.